# How to dynamically change the height of ListBoxItem UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I need your help.

At this moment I'm making a notification panel. And I need to change the height of `ListBoxItem` in response to a number of message's lines. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msc3I.png).
As you can see the first notification didn't increase its height and `TextBlock` with timecode has just disappeared.

Here's my code sample:

```
<ListBox Width="350" Padding="0,0,0,10" Name="notificationArray">
    <ListBoxItem Padding="10" MinHeight="80" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray" Text="Channel name"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="This is very long notification. One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten."/>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" Text="HH:MM TT" FontSize="13"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

As you can see here, I've already tried `Height="Auto"` and `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions? Anyway, thanks in advance.

P.S. Problem is definitely in `ListBoxItem`. I've already experimented with `ListBox` and `StackPanel`

P.P.S Here's a lager sample:

```
<Popup Grid.Column="6" Margin="0,50,0,0" Name="notificationPane" LostFocus="notificationPane_LostFocus" IsOpen="False" IsLightDismissEnabled="True">
    <StackPanel Width="350" Background="WhiteSmoke" Padding="0,10,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="Notifications" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="You have no any notification" Name="noNotifText" Foreground="Gray" FontStyle="Italic" Padding="10" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <StackPanel Name="notificationPanel" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ListBox Width="350" Padding="0,0,0,10" Name="notificationArray">
                    <ListBoxItem Padding="10" MinHeight="80">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray" Text="Channel name"/>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="This is very long notification. One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten."/>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" Text="HH:MM TT" FontSize="13"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Padding="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightGray" MinHeight="80" Height="100">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray" Text="Channel name"/>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="This is very long notification. One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten."/>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" Text="HH:MM TT" FontSize="13"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
                <Button Content="Clear all" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Your code snippet are not enough to reproduce the issue, could you please upload more XAML code? How you add the data? By the way, try to change `VerticalAlignment` to `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"`.

Comment: 1. Additional code is absolutely unnecessary, but here it is.
2. I don't add any data programmatically at this moment. I'm just writing a UI base for the application.
3. Already tried. Just have forgotten to mention

Comment: i removed the popup for testing; but not really able to reproduce? can you add more info what you are seeing (screenshot?)?

Comment: @DaveSmits here's a [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnQ5WkWqz7MKi78FBQCntBWNS4j4Tw). And here's my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/XFox111/foxtube-UWP) just in case (development branch).

Comment: @XFox it show perfectly to me. No Textblock is hiding

Comment: even based on your screenshot i dont see text that is hiding? the entire text "This is very long notification. One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten." is visible?

Comment: @DaveSmits yes, it is. As you can see in the screenshot both notifications almost identical except that fact that on the 2nd notification I've set the height manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download your whole project from the development branch that you uploaded to the GitHub and find the issue. Since you defined defined the global style for the `ListBoxItem` in [`App.xaml`](https://github.com/XFox111/foxtube-UWP/blob/development/FoxTube/App.xaml) of the project, which set the `Height` property of `ListBoxItem` as `50` that limited the `ListBoxItem` to show the content.

To resolve your issue, commented this style, or set a fixed height for the first `ListBoxItem` as you did for the second one, or set a larger `MinHeight` for the first item.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!--<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    </Style>-->
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="ItemIcon">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,20,2"/>
    </Style>
...
</Application.Resources>
```